# jQuery shows random records every time

Tags: jquery

I am retrieving data filtered by, all, weekly, monthly and yearly from an excel file between the two dates. By default I want it to display 'All Records' but somehow it displays random data every time the page is accessed or refreshed i.e. sometimes weekly, monthly or yearly. Is it possible to have All records by default? i don't know why it keeps showing random data.

The tabs are anchor links:
[All] [Last Week] [Last Month] [Last Year]

Here's my jQuery Code:

```
    // All
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var todayDate = new Date();
    var endDate = todayDate.getDate() + '/' + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (todayDate.getFullYear() + 100);
    var d = new Date();
    var st = d.setDate(todayDate.getDate() - 111365);
    var startDate = d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
    $('#allrecordsstart').val(startDate);
    $('#allrecordsend').val(endDate);
    $('#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1').jtable('load', {
        StartDate: startDate,
        EndDate: endDate
    });

    $('#allrecords').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var startDate = $('#allrecordsstart').val();
        var endDate = $('#allrecordsend').val();

        $('#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1').jtable('load', {
            StartDate: startDate,
            EndDate: endDate

        });

    });

    // Week
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var todayDate = new Date();
    var endDate = todayDate.getDate() + '/' + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + todayDate.getFullYear();
    var d = new Date();
    var st = d.setDate(todayDate.getDate() - 7);
    var startDate = d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
    $('#lastWeekstart').val(startDate);
    $('#lastWeekend').val(endDate);

    $('#lastWeek').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var startDate = $('#lastWeekstart').val();
        var endDate = $('#lastWeekend').val();

        $('#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1').jtable('load', {
            StartDate: startDate,
            EndDate: endDate

        });

    });

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Month
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var todayDate = new Date();
    var endDate = todayDate.getDate() + '/' + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + todayDate.getFullYear();
    var d = new Date();
    var st = d.setDate(todayDate.getDate() - 30);
    var startDate = d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
    $('#monthstart').val(startDate);
    $('#monthend').val(endDate);

    $('#lastMonth').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var startDate = $('#monthstart').val();
        var endDate = $('#monthend').val();

        $('#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1').jtable('load', {
            StartDate: startDate,
            EndDate: endDate

        });

    });

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Year
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var todayDate = new Date();
    var endDate = todayDate.getDate() + '/' + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + todayDate.getFullYear();
    var d = new Date();
    var st = d.setDate(todayDate.getDate() - 365);
    var startDate = d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
    $('#yearstart').val(startDate);
    $('#yearend').val(endDate);

    $('#lastYear').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var startDate = $('#yearstart').val();
        var endDate = $('#yearend').val();

        $('#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1').jtable('load', {
            StartDate: startDate,
            EndDate: endDate

        });

    });

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page load you seem to trigger 4 different `.jtable('load', ...)` calls - one for each list :

```
// this is called on page load :
$('#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1').jtable('load', {
    StartDate: startDate,
    EndDate: endDate
});

$('#lastMonth').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var startDate = $('#monthstart').val();
    var endDate = $('#monthend').val();

    // this is called when clicking on #lastMonth :
    $('#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1').jtable('load', {
        StartDate: startDate,
        EndDate: endDate

    });

});
```

Remove the useless calls : on page load, if you want to load the `"All records"` list, load that one, and delete the three others.

---

Other points to check :

- Open your browser console, and check what requests get sent to your server. Hunt down the unwanted requests (look for the places which can trigger them in your javascript code)
- In the network tab, check that the server answers with correct data. If not, you will have to debug your server side code (<- PHP / ruby / python / ASP.net ...)

Comment: thanks for your fix - I tried that before posting the question in here and have tried any other possible combinations. Is there anything else you can think of that I probably missing in it in here? I have updated my code with your suggestion.. and thanks again :)

Comment: Or is it possible to force 'All Records' somehow to show? thanks :)

Comment: thanks for your help, I think it was a caching issue. cleared everything and ran your code and it fixed it.